# Waiting for Dropdown to Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 pages called A.jsp and B.jsp that contain HTML and Javascript code. When I move from page A to page B, I would like to assign values to some drop downs on page B. But when I move to page B, the values in the drop downs have not yet loaded so I cannot set them. Is there a work around to this issue?

Comment: Please add the code you currently have so people can answer better

Comment: I would suggest using cookies.

Comment: @RamenChef: I have used Sessions to store data I want to pass between page A and B. I still need to find a way for the dropdowns in page B to load before I set their values.

Comment: @Student Are you talking about a <select> element on page B? How is this select element getting its content?

Comment: @JayB: The values for page B dropdown are being populated by a Controller written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Store the desired value for the page B dropdown **while on page A**:

```
localStorage.setItem('page_B_dropdown_val','the desired value');
```

Now when you say "not yet loaded" I assume you're loading the values for page B dropdown via ajax?

```
var asdf = localStorage.getItem('page_B_dropdown_val');
page_B_dropdown_element.value = asdf !== null ? asdf : page_B_dropdown_element.value;
```